# compact subset of the product space $X\times X$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space,consider the product space $X\times X$.can we deduce that any compact subset of $X\times X$ is the form of $K\times K$,where $K$ is the compact subset of $X$.

Comment: No. Consider $[0,\,1]\times[0,\,2]$ in $[0,\,2]\times[0,\,2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $[0,1]\times [0,2]$ in  $[0,2]\times[0,2]$.

Comment: So all the compact subsets of $X\otimes X$ are the form of $K_1\times K_2$,where $K_1,K_2$ are comapct subsets of $X$?

Comment: no, not thats not true.

Comment: any counterexamples?

Comment: @math112358 $\{(x,x): x \in [0,1]\}$ is compact and not of the form $K_1 \times K_2$; any closed subset of $[0,1]^2$ is compact, e.g. all graphs of functions.